# iPhone native app + integrate payment / purchase to buy products

Tags: iphone, payment-gateway

I am developing a native iPhone app, where end user can purchase calling cards of different rates.

The problem I am facing is that, I don't what can be several options to integrate payment / online purchase feature and they can be integrated.

Few sites I have read that, you can implement this using In App Purchase, but there using In App purchase Apple will take 30% of payment. Also, I need to register each of my product with Apple -> iTunes Connect -> Manage In App Purchase, which is again not a feasible thing to do. As my products would have different rates and they get updated regularly, so every time I have make changes in iTunes Connect.

Another option can be to integrate Paypal for purchases but, here I have open the web interface (either safari browser or UIWebView) from native app when it comes to make payment. Problem here is that, opening the web interface would fine, but I need to come to native app and same point in the app from where I did the payment. Also, I don't have prior experience of integrating Paypal.

Please guide me to find the best suitable option to integrate payment feature in native app.

Comment: R u able to find the answer....Please let me know I am also looking for the same.

Comment: Even if you were to get a solution for upgrades paying via paypal, I'm not 100% sure that Apple would like this. Because to them, by not using In app purchasing, they're losing their cut. So I would imagine they'd just reject your binary.

Comment: Also, I don't want to speak for anyone else but there is no way in this world I would pay extra for something unless it was secure, such as the in app purchasing provided by Apple. You might have more look in the Cydia store but lets not talk about that here.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need to read the Apple-iOS-Standard-Agreement, to find answers about InAppPurchase:

Attachment-2 to the iOS-Standard-Agreement Feb. 15th 2011, 1.1, 2.1, 2.2:
... this makes clear that you are not allowed to use InAppPurchase for selling calling cards. InAppPurchase is only allowed for content & functionality you provide the user within your app.

AS InAppPurchase is not the way you can go, you may use the Mobile Payments Library for iOS, PayPal release last year. The lib is well documented and ships with sample code: 
https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile/mep